# how to identify sequence pattern in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to solve this sequence pattern problem.

example:

[image]

I want to identify students who had duration sequence of 1 to 3.
The max row number should have 3 to be meet this condition.
The output I'm expecting is 
count of students who meet the criteria: 2 (asd,jkc)

I tried to use max(row_num) function and if the next row of duration is bigger than the current row, then it will meet the criteria..

Comment: What if you had 1-2-3?  Or 3-2-1?  Or a myriad of other possibilities?

Comment: please add to your question your expected output for your example input and include what you have tried so far and how this did not yet work properly

Comment: Will `Row_Num` always start at 1 and continue sequentially? It is okay to just base it on the Max of Row_Num?